# "unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method" Python Gmail API using Service Account

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I keep getting the above error and I am not sure how to solve this.
I have enabled Domain wide Delegation and also authorized the Client-Id in 'Manage API Access'

### My Code looks like this:

```
"""
Sample program    
"""

import googleapiclient.discovery
import json
import googleapiclient.errors 
from google.oauth2 import service_account 

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'abcd.json' 

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)

scoped_credentials = 
credentials.with_scopes(['https://mail.google.com/'])
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('abcd')

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail','v1',credentials = delegated_credentials) 

try:
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='abcd').execute()
except Exception as err:
    print err
```

Has anyone got this working ? If so please point out why I am getting the error.

Comment: Got it working. It was a silly mistake :) .

Comment: Changed delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('abcd') ----> delegated_credentials = scoped_credentials.with_subject('abcd')

Comment: After solving this problem, I wonder if you would mind telling me what I'm doing wrong? The second effort in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206251/authenticating-gmail-api-access-programmatically seems to do pretty much what yours does, but puts the scopes into the credential creation.