# GCP Authentication: RefreshError

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gmail, authorization

In order to round-trip test mail sending code in our GCP backend I am sending an email to a GMail inbox and attempting to verify its arrival. The current mechanism for authentication to the GMail API is fairly standard, pasted from the GMail API documentation and embedded in a function:

```
def authenticate():
    """Authenticates to the Gmail API using data in credentials.json,
    returning the service instance for use in queries etc."""
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CRED_FILE_PATH, SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    return service
```

`CRED_FILE_PATH` points to a downloaded credentials file for the service. The absence of the `token.json` file triggers its re-creation after an authentication interaction via a browser window, as does the token's expiry.

This is an integration test that must run headless (i.e. with no interaction whatsoever). When re-authentication is required the test currently raises an exception when the authentication flow starts to access `sys.argv`, which means it sees the arguments to `pytest`!

I've been trying to find out how to authenticate reliably using a mechanism that does not require user interaction (such as an API key). Nothing in the documentation or on Stackoverflow seems to answer this question.

A more recent effort uses the keyfile from a service account with GMail delegation to avoid the interactive Oauth2 flows.

```
def authenticate():
    """Authenticates to the Gmail API using data in g_suite_access.json,
    returning the service instance for use in queries etc."""
    main_cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        CRED_FILE_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)
    # Establish limited credential to minimise any damage.
    credentials = main_cred.with_subject(GMAIL_USER)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return service
```

On trying to use this service with

```
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',
                                    q=f'subject:{subject}').execute()
```

I get:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError:
  ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.',
   '{\n "error": "unauthorized_client",\n "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."\n}')
```

I get the feeling there's something fundamental I'm not understanding.

Comment: Why can not you use IMAP access to the gmail account to perform this integration test? I understand that this is not what you wanted to get help with, but this seems to be much simpler to achieve the goal of integration test as described.

Comment: I did consider that, but since we'll want to use Gmail API services for other purposes later this would just be kicking the problem down the road.

Comment: Ironically, investigating the IMAP solution further, I had trouble authenticating with IMAP, and further research led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413301/gmail-login-failure-using-python-and-imaplib), where the answer is ... to use OAuth2 authentication!!

Comment: Well, that is only if you disable "access for less secure apps" as it says there. So technically it's not a stopper for checking that e-mail arrives - just need to change this setting to allow. But, since you need GMail API later anyway, that's clearly not a permanent solution, just possibly a temporary workaround. IMAP totally works though - I move gmail inboxes contents elsewhere using it.

Comment: Yes, I now have an IMAP fallback solution, but we've agreed for the moment this can be a manually-run integration test. We don't need to check our email channels every minute, but it wold be nice to know everything worked after a new vendor release, for example. I'm still hoping the bounty drags in an answer, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: [Maybe this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736062/sending-email-fails-when-two-factor-authentication-is-on-for-gmail)

Comment: 'Fraid not, but all such questions welcome. I've now abandoned the IMAP solution in favour of  `flow_from_client_secrets` - if we are running interactively the tester can assert the right authentication credentials.

Comment: The gmail id that you are trying with, is it a gsuite id or a simple gmail id(@gmail.com)?

Comment: It's G-suite (our own domain - one error was to try and login in under an aliased domain, which won't work).

Comment: I tried running your code and it's works absolutely fine. Please check two things -
1. If you are authorising the correct scopes.
2. I've generally seen this error come when scopes are missing from service account authorization. Have you followed this correctly - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation ?

Comment: @holdenweb did you get a chance to check this?

Comment: Yes, very useful. As you suspected, the service account authorization wasn't correctly scoped.

Comment: Great! Missed out on the bounty though :)

Comment: I believe it's necessary to write an answer to claim a bounty, and there was only one answer when the bounty was up. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, it's okay. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service account needs to be authorized or it cant access the emails for the domain.

> "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method"

Means that you have not authorized it properly; check [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)

Source: [Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method Gmail API C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42784640/5675325)